# Error con @viewChild con renderer2

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

En el archivo index.html tengo lo siguiente

```
 <body #body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

y en otro componente quiero tomar el body y asignarle una clase al body

```
 @ViewChild("body") body: ElementRef
constructor(private render: Renderer2  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.render.addClass(this.body.nativeElement,"login-body")
  }
```

pero tengo el siguiente error  core.js:4196 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

En si, tienes dos errores, el `viewchild` buscara los elementos hijo del componente, obviamente el body es muy superior, te recomiendo usar algo mas nativo de javascript, lo otro es que deberias implementar esto en el `AfterViewInit` que es cuando un elemento esta renderizado

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sería utilizar `document.body` directamente para asignar la clase, es decir:

index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Componente

```
export class MyAwesomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'awesome-class');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'awesome-class');
  }

}
```

En este caso, hacerlo dentro de `ngOnInit` es válido ya que el body está renderizado.